# Clear Cache on AWS Lightsail Server

Tags: wordpress, caching, amazon-lightsail

I have a wordpress site on a lightsail instance. It seems to be heavily caching my site updates. I can not figure a way to clear the cache completely I tried following the instructions here.

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/amazon-lightsail-resetting-distribution-cache

but there is no "Cache Tab" as it describes in this documentation. I have been going in circles here. I just need a way to force the cache to just be completely flushed when I need.

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find  a way to do this--I'm seeing the same thing you are, no "Cache Tab" on the Networking tab.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have cloudfront distribution configured in lightsail which is caching your content. If you do, then you need to go to networking menu of lightsail, select distribution and from there you will be able to see 'Cache' tab.